# Calling a variable by a string's value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, function, variables

I've got a pickle I can't seem to find a solution for.

Let's say I have the following code in VBA, which basically, whatever is given for the function Example as a string argument, calls the variable with the same name as the string argument and returns the value of the variable that's been called (if my explanation made any sense):

```
Private EnterMenu, ExitMenu as String

Function Example(name)

    Select Case name
        Case "EnterMenu"
            Example = EnterMenu
        Case "ExitMenu"
            Example = ExitMenu
        'and so on
    End Select
End Function
```

That's fine and all, but is there a way without writing a case for every single possibility, for example

```
Function Example(name)

    Example=Value(name)

End Function
```

So that it just grabs the value of the string "name", gets the variable with the same name and returns the value of that variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare your public variable as an object and set it up as a dictonary, like so:

```
Public diValues As Object

Sub InitPubVar()

    Set diValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    diValues.Add "EnterMenu", "Opening the menu"
    diValues.Add "ExitMenu", "Closing the menu"

End Sub
```

Now that your global dictionary has been created and populated, you can pull the values from it using the keys you set, which seems to be what you're looking for:

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox diValues("EnterMenu")  '--> shows a box displaying the string "Opening the menu"

End Sub
```

Note that if you are on an older version of Excel, you may need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  This can be done within the VB Editor -> Tools -> References.

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't have an easy way to dynamically call string variables. You can use the `CallByName` function for objects, which gets you there if you are [willing to create a custom class object](https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/59475-Using-string-to-reference-a-variable-(Excel-Office-2003)) for your variable. Or you can look at creating a named range for each variable you plan on using, setting the range's value to equal that of the variable and then calling it with 
 the`Range("YourVariable").Value` within your code.

Some developers feel it's best to avoid using `Select Case`; if you have a lot of cases you're switching between, you might want to reconsider your logic flow. This is a topic of debate among developers, and I don't know that I can pick a side, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) explains some of the potential disadvantages and alternatives others have come up with to avoid switch-based logic.